# Neo4j Cypher - how to query 'inherited' reations on a child-node?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-cql

I want to use Cypher to query all specifications that are valif for a product, but with the specifications defined at different parent levels of the product.

I have a data model that represents a product categorisation tree with levels C1, C2, C3, ... and at the lowest level products P. To simplify the maintenance and data-entry of product specifications, the validity of product specifications is defined at the categorisation levels. The products 'inherit' the specifications that are valid for all their parent categories, up to the root of the categorisation tree.

The (simplified) data-model is shown in the image. In this case product specifications are defined for categorisation levels C1, C2 and C3. The product is connected to the lowest categorisation level C3.
My objective is to query all specifications that are valid for product P, based on their relations to the categorisation levels C1, C2 and C3.

[image: graph model]

I have the following questions:

1. Is this possible with a single Cypher query?
2. What is the best query strategy in a large database? Use a query? Create real relations for all valid specifications for a product instead of querying the 'inherited' specifications?
3. Change the datamodel?

Other tips?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find all specifications of a product by MATCHing patterns of variable length.

Assuming you have a parameter `productId`, you would use something like this

```
MATCH (p:PRODUCT {productId:$productiId)-[:BELONGS_TO*]->(c:Category)<-[:VALID_FOR]-(s:Specification)
RETURN s
```

to retrieve the relevant specifications.

Since you seem to be working on bills of materials, some things you may want to look at:

Management of complex product specifications by splitting it up in "atoms" https://www.slideshare.net/neo4j/graphtour-neo4j-murrelektronik

and

An example of how you can keep track of versions of your BOM : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iMraBHtTqE

Disclosure : I'm a member of the Graphileon team, and involved in what is shown in the slide deck and video.

Comment: Thanks! 

The '*' behind the "BELONGS_TO" relation, indicating a [Variable-length pattern matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength), did the trick. 

I need to take some time to read through the whole Cypher manual :)